# Kotlin: return immutable collection from getter while using mutable inside

Tags: java, collections, kotlin

I have some field which is collection, which can be mutated inside service containing it, and some other services should be able to access it without possibility to mutate it by themselves.

In java it would can be implemented like this:

```
public class Test {

    private final List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Integer> getList() {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
    }
}
```

In kotlin I store this field declared as `MutableList`:

```
val someCollection: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()
    get() = unmodifiableList(field)
```

But then getter obviously would return object with type `MutableList`.

Ideally I want to achieve something like this:

```
val someCollection: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()
        get() = unmodifiableList(field) as List // <-- returns List instead of MutableList
```

In other words is it possible change signature of generated getter to return another interface. Most probably answer is no, and I wonder why? Is it believed to be some bad practice?

I saw that there is possibility to do something like this:

```
private val _someCollection: MutableList<Int> = ArrayList()
val someCollection: List<Int>
    get() = unmodifiableList(field)
```

But it does seems even worse then manually created getter, as it creates one more field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's not currently possible in Kotlin. In fact, the current design forces the getters to have the same return type to that of the whole property.

Typically, the workaround is, as you noticed, to use a backing property.

Alternatively, you can define an interface with a `List` property, implement it with a `MutableList` in a class, and expose instances of the class using the interface:

```
interface SomeInterface {
    val someList: List<Int>
}

internal class SomeClass : SomeInterface {
    override val someList: MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf()
}

fun getSomeInterface(): SomeInterface =
    SomeClass().apply { someList += listOf(1, 2, 3) }
```

See: [a related discussion](https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/idiomatic-way-to-expose-a-property-using-a-more-narrow-type/4863).